# How to return correct results and list of errors

Tags: java, error-handling

I am puzzled by the following design of the method:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> foo(Parameter p){ ... }
```

This method takes a complex `Parameter` and returns a map name -> value. In many cases, based on certain underlying calues of the parameter, the resulting map will be the same, furthermore, there are only a few different maps that can ever be returned, so these will be cached. However, when the map is initially created, there can potentially be different types of errors - certain String value might be incorrect, certain value might be < 0 and therefore should be skipped etc. These errors might be of different nature then. I would like to return this map, but also be able to flag these errros, ideally only once, when the initialization of each map is performed. What would be the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Cache the exception as well, and throw it when foo() is called.

Comment: what do you mean cache the exception? I want to return correct results, so that they are processed. If I throw an exception, then the callers method won't be able to do that

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point. If a result was generated, I see no reason for which the caller should know that there was an internal exception that has been already handled.

Comment: There might not be any "Exceptions" - just things to flag

Comment: It's the same, whether you call them 'exceptions' or 'error flags'. For non-error flags, it could make sense, though. In which case I'd have a method getFlagXYZ().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly unusual requirement - if you *can* generate a valid result in spite of the internal errors, you should probably return that result; and if not, throw the exception.

But if you do want to return this additional information, then I see you have broadly two options available:

1. **Object-oriented, mutable state**.  When you're running `foo()`, accumulate any internal errors in some field.  Expose an additional `getFooErrors()` method to allow callers to inspect what happened.  And possibly a `getFooErrorSeverity()` method if you need to tell callers the degree to which these errors impacted on the quality of your result map.
2. **Immutable/functional**.  Return the information from above (exceptions and maybe a severity score) as part of your method.  Instead of returning a `Map<String, BigDecimal>`, return an object which contains the map, as well as the exception details.  E.g:

   ```
   public class FooResult {
       public final Map<String, BigDecimal> result;
       public final List<Throwable> errors;
       public final int errorSeverity;

       // Constructor elided
   }
   ```

The first approach is similar to how `java.io.PrintWriter` works in the standard library.  It swallows any IOExceptions encountered by its I/O methods, and exposes a [checkError()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError%28%29) method to allow callers to see if the writer encountered any exceptions.

I prefer the second because it doesn't impact thread-safety, it gives the client all the information up-front, and it's neatly coupled with the scope where the error was encountered.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one right way to do this, but what about creating special class `FooResult` that would contain your map and list of errors (although I would rather call it a Warning, since unrecoverable errors are usually reported with exceptions), eg:

```
FooResult foo(Parameter p){ ... }

class FooResult {
  Map<String, BigDecimal> result;
  List<Error> errors;
}
```

where `Error` could be a class containing all error information you need (eg. code, message, exception, etc), for instance:

```
class Error {
  int code;
  String message;
  Throwable cause; // optional, depending on error
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively the list of `Error`s could be passed as a parameter and filled by the method if necessary, eg:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> foo(Parameter p, List<Error> errors) { 
  ... 
  if (error) {
    errors.add(new Error(10, "Bad error"));
  }
}
```